# Manga where the female main character goes back in time and wants to leave her family, but her family loves her

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's a manga where the main character is a female and she goes back in time and becomes young again. This time, she wanted to leave her family, but her family loves her; it's just that she was not qualified to become an heir, because she doesn't have any power, I think, as far as I remember, and her family didn't know that. When her brother was born, he cried and he lef

Comment: Hi. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead? Why did she go back in time? Did she die? If so, how? And it looks like you didn't finish typing the last sentence; can you edit the question to finish it?